# Replace all carriage returns in file

Tags: vb.net

I'm sorry to ask this but I've exhausted my searches. I'm looking to take in an SGM or XML file and replace all carriage returns with a space. Everything I've found has been to remove carriage returns from a string and I need to take in a while file.

Code I've been trying

```
    sFileName = txtFileName.Text
    Dim FileInfo As New FileInfo(sFileName)
    Dim FileLocation As String = FileInfo.FullName

    Dim FileContents As String = File.ReadAllText(FileLocation)
    FileContents.Replace(vbCr, FileContents)

    File.WriteAllText(FileLocation, FileContents)
```

And Also

```
    sFileName = txtFileName.Text
    Dim FileInfo As New FileInfo(sFileName)
    Dim FileLocation As String = FileInfo.FullName

    Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FileLocation)
    fileReader = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(fileReader, vbCr, " ")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(FileLocation, fileReader, False)
```

Comment: `FileContents.Replace(vbCr, FileContents)`  This makes no sense.  Replace carriage returns with the entire contents of the file, over and over again for every carriage return?  Replace is a Function, it *returns* the result.  Your code is ignoring the return part.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm sorry what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the `FileContents` part of `.Replace(vbCr, FileContents)` for whatever you want in your fileContent string for whatever string you want instead of a carriage return.

Comment: `FileContents = FileContents.Replace(vbCr, " ")`

Comment: @LarsTech that didn't work

Comment: Define didn't work?  What was the output?  Did you examine this in the debugger?  What does the file look like in NotePad before and after?

Comment: @LarsTech Ah thank you for reminding me to look in the debugger. It was vbLF instead of vbCr

Answer (score 0):

If it is vbCrLf that you are after then...

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Your file path and name.")
    Dim noHardReturns = String.Join(" ", lines)
End Sub
```